# ADFS - Get user information

Tags: adfs, adfs4.0

I need to authenticate myself with an AddIn (excel, word, powerpoint) in office 365.
The customer has a local ADFS that he would like to use to authenticate the user.
I would therefore like to authenticate myself on local ADFS, retrieve the token and user information and then use the AddIn and Azure Rights managment (RMS).
Authentication to ADFS must be done automatically, without entering login and password.

Comment: After setup correctly ADFS, I used ADAL v3 for autentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way of doing this is to setup ADFS as a [federated domain](http://www.thatlazyadmin.com/configure-adfs-office-365/) to Azure AD. Office 365 runs on Azure AD.

ADFS supports Windows Integrated Auth so a user logged into the domain joined PC will seamlessly log into ADFS.